# How to modify second-to-last line inside a range in sed

Tags: sed, range

In sed I do some modifications for lines that are in a range but the second-to-last line need a special modification that other lines don't need. So my question is how can I detect the second-to-last line inside a range ?

I have that kind of data :

```sh
a,
b,
c,
KEY1,
d,
e,
f,
KEY2,
g,
h,
i,
...
```

Actually I can only put "version1" for every lines between KEY1 and KEY2 :

```sh
a,
b,
c,
KEY1,
version1_d,
version1_e,
version1_f,
KEY2,
g,
h,
i,
```

My code :

```sh
echo "a, b, c, KEY1, d, e, f, KEY2, g, h, i," | tr " " "\n" | \
sed '
/KEY1/,/KEY2/ {
  /KEY1/ n
  $ s/.*/version2_&/
  /KEY2/! s/.*/version1_&/
}
'
```

I tried to use "$" inside the range but it search the real last line of the file.

and I would like to get :

```sh
a,
b,
c,
KEY1,
version1_d,
version1_e,
version2_f,
KEY2,
g,
h,
i,
```

That is, a different modification for the letter "f" i.e the second-to-last line of the range /KEY1/,/KEY2/

I thought about use "N" and check if the pattern space contains 'f,\nKEY2' but, it would not work if the number of rows in the range are even (which is possible in my case) and I don't know how to do that either x).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '/^KEY1/{:a;N;/\nKEY2/!s/(.*\n)/\1version1_/;ta;s/(.*\nversion)1/\12/}' file
```

Instead of using a range, use a loop. Gather the lines between `KEY1` and `KEY2` and insert `version1_` in front of the last line until `KEY2` is encountered. Then substitute `2` for `1` in the last but one line in the pattern space.

Comment: Thank you  ! I didn't know much about loop in sed but it works great !

Answer (score 0):

With any awk in any shell on every UNIX box and trivially modified to do anything else you also want to do to each block:

```
$ cat tst.awk
/KEY2/ {
    for ( lineNr=1; lineNr<=numLines; lineNr++ ) {
        print (lineNr == numLines ? "version2_" : "version1_") block[lineNr]
    }
    inBlock = numLines = 0
}
inBlock { block[++numLines]=$0; next }
/KEY1/ { inBlock=1 }
{ print }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
a,
b,
c,
KEY1,
version1_d,
version1_e,
version2_f,
KEY2,
g,
h,
i,
...
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but is numLines a variable I have to initialize ? Because number of lines between KEY1 and KEY2 is not fixed in files I want to edit so it'll need another step to determine numLines.

Comment: Yes it's a variable, no you don't have to initialize it. The code does not assume anything about how many lines are between KEY1 and KEY2, it is counting the number of lines between each KEY1 and KEY2 pair, saving those lines in an array indexed by the current calculated relative line number between them, and then when KEY2 is found using the value it calculated to print version1 or version2. Try it with various numbers of lines between KEY1 and KEY2 pairs. Add `{print "TRC", inBlock+0, numLines+0, $0}` at the top to trace it if you like.

Comment: I forgot to reply but thank you for your explanations, it's more clear for me now.